# Line Breakpoints not suspending thread when debugging in Android Studio

Tags: android, debugging, android-emulator

I'm using android studio 1.5.1 and trying to debug a very simple application on an emulator. I've tried emulators with version 18-23 and all do the same thing. Basically it will suspend the thread for method level breakpoints but not for any line break points.

Comment: have you got minify enabled?
could be http://stackoverflow.com/a/28860937/1856361

Answer (score 17):

If you are trying to debug multithread apps in Android Studio, you could have troubles with some of your breakpoints, so it's better to enable an Android Studio option to pause all threads by default setting.

Double click your breakpoint and make default the "Suspend All threads" option.
[image]

Comment: it doesn't work with suspend all, especially when you use Room