# Android debugger does not stop at breakpoints after minifyEnabled false

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, android-gradle-plugin

The debugger does not stop on any breakpoints. I tried clearing all breakpoints and adding them back in but I am seeing debug statements in the console.

According to  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28836243/android-studios-debugger-not-stopping-at-breakpoints-within-library-modules/28860937#28860937), Inside build.gradle for your app module, disable minifyEnable for my build variant and change it to false.

```
debug {
        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
```

I did it also but also but still same problem.

Comment: shrinkResources true this is causing the issue

Comment: I agree, I think you should delete this line `shrinkResources true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're in debug configuration you don't need to shrink resources or add proguard

```
debug {
    debuggable true
    minifyEnabled false
    shrinkResources true
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
}
```

change to

```
debug {
    debuggable true
    minifyEnabled false
   // shrinkResources true
  //  proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
}
```