# Breakpoints not working on Android Studio 3.3

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, breakpoints

After upgrading Android Studio to version 3.3 this week, some breakpoints are not being recognized as valid, and are not stopping the thread.

Am I missing anything?

[image]

Comment: Have been on 3.3 for a while, no issues here. Make sure you debugger is attached to the instance and you've done a project resync/clean/rebuild.

Comment: I had to upgrade gradle as well to clear up other unrelated issues

Comment: Thanks! Everything is up to date (3.3 and gradle 4.10.1), but still facing the breakpoint issue. :/

Comment: those breakpoints are in your code or some SDK code or 3rd parties libs?

Comment: In my code. One is at an "init" method of a Fragment. The other one is inside a Retrofit request callback.

Comment: and what about other breakpoints in the same class? tried to add in the first line of your `Activity.onCreate` where you call `super.onCreate`? is it fired?

Comment: Yes, I just added one right above the one that's not firing in my "init". It gets fired. When I hit F9, the next (original) one is ignored. This one doesn't have the checkmark when I'm running in debug mode. The above one has it.

Comment: hmmmm, are you sure the code goes thru those lines? tried adding `Log.d`? if so, i would simply `rm -rf build` folder and try again

Comment: Pretty sure. There's a condition on the second breakpoint. The code inside it is executed. I'll try to clean up the build folder. That's something I haven't tried yet.

Comment: @pskink Have found it. Not exactly what you said, but the breakpoint is not being hit. It's on a "if" statement line. Which used to work does not work anymore. It worked when I added the breakpoint inside the conditional statement. :/
Would you mind to write this answer @pskink?

Comment: I will add to the weirdness. I am having this behavior only with "if`" inside of lambdas/anonymous. If statement breakpoints work fine within their own classes... Ideas?

Comment: Try to add your breakpoint inside the "if" statement. It did work for me.

Comment: What I noticed is that the if statements that have complicated logic in them do not work. So an "if (object.getSomething() == something)" will not work, but if you assign that to a value and then use the value in the statement it works fine... mystery deepens.

Comment: I filled a bug report to Google. Here you can track it: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/123651520

Comment: Does this answer your question? [android debugger does not stop at breakpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293415/android-debugger-does-not-stop-at-breakpoints)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is in the build tool chain (gradle, d8/r8). Problem is **fixed** in `Android Studio 3.4 Beta 1` with `gradle 3.4.0-beta01`.

---

Or a workaround solution for this issue can be used by locally updating the top-level **build.gradle** configuration for your project:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'http://storage.googleapis.com/r8-releases/raw' // ADD THIS.
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools:r8:1.3.55'  // ADD THIS. Must be before the Gradle Plugin for Android.
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3'
    } 
}
```

Once the next point release of Android Gradle Plugins takes place these changes can be removed.

---

For more information, see: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122450679

Comment: Fixed on Android Studio 3.3.2

Comment: @rafanasil I still suffer from this bug after upgrade to AS 3.3.2 last night. The same  error happen with AS 3.5 canary 6 too. Which Gradle build tool version that you are using?

Comment: I'm using 3.3.2. After upgrading Android Studio and Gradle build tool I've got my breakpoints working fine.

Answer (score 7):

Found the answer with the help of @pskink.
"If" statements are "invalid" locales for breakpoints. See the checkmarks below:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by invalid? Also I commented on the question about the behavior I am getting.

Comment: "Invalid" means the Debugger won't reach that breakpoint. See the checkmarks on the breakpoints above during the execution. They're valid ones.

Comment: I see. Then again your answer does not answer why this works this way now. if's were "valid" before. Now they aren't under circumstances (my comment under the question). Why is that happening?

Comment: I am afraid that the "answer" is somewhat helpful, but does not provide a solution. I second @MadDim, why is that happening, it was working on AS 3.2. This is total bullshit. Probably is caused by some code optimization in the new AS/compiler/JVM...

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. The problem is solved by upgrading Android Studio from `3.6.2` to `4.0.0`

Answer (score 0):

it works for android 4.0.1. there is a button "attach debugger to android process" on top menu bar. click it and select the process. then the debugger will hit the break point.