# Breakpoints not Working in Android Studio 3.3

Tags: android-studio-3.3

After noticing that some breakpoints are not getting hit, I found this post that answers why:

[Breakpoints not working on Android Studio 3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54311642/breakpoints-not-working-on-android-studio-3-3)

I don't recall this happening prior to Android Studio 3.3. Is there any way to stop this behavior so that breakpoints will get hit on conditional statements?

Answer (score 4):

Found here [setting minifyEnabled false in the debug build is the best practice.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28860937/10180097)

I just change minifyEnabled in build.grandle to 'false' on debug buildTypes and it works!

Comment: did it really work for you? Did you really had the same issue has @user982687, I already had minifyEnable = false on every buildType and upon upgrading I have the exact same issue has the OP. What bugs me the most, is that breakpoints on conditional statements are the most useful to me, and they were working before!

Comment: I don't know why Khdkls's answer is not selected as "Best Answer"!

Comment: When proguard is enabled, the breakpoints won't work. The method names and attributes would have been obfuscated.

Answer (score 3):

**Rebuild** solved my problem.

`clean & rebuild`

Invalidates caches/restart if necessary

Answer (score 0):

In my case I fixed the problem by updating Android Studio to the latest version 4.0.1.