# Android Studio 3.3 Java 8 debugger "this" is not available in lambdas and cannot stop on "if"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, debugging

I have changed my Android Java version to 8 wanting to simplify some code writing. An issue I am having, and I cannot figure out, is that I am getting a `'this' is not available` in the debugger for the class properties when they are inside a lambda expression. As mentioned in the title I have updated to the latest Android Studio 3.3.

I have been searching around for some time now trying to figure out what I am doing wrong but with no luck.

Another issue that I am having is that when in lambdas (and anonymous in general) the debugger cannot stop on `if` statements (visually the breakpoint red circle never gets a tick mark), something I am pretty sure I could do before. Are there changes (or settings) in Android Studio 3.3 that caused this? What am I missing?

Any ideas/solution would be much appreciated.

**EDIT:**

There is another question concerning the `if` breakpoints [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54311642/breakpoints-not-working-on-android-studio-3-3/54312341?noredirect=1#comment95546394_54312341) specifically. The OP there gives a very generic answer that I am not satisfied with and it doesn't answer the why.

What I noticed is that the if statements that have complicated logic in them do not get active breakpoints. So an `if (object.getSomething() == something)` will not work, but if you assign that to a value and then use the value in the comparison it works just fine... mystery deepens.

Comment: There are some tips here: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8906264. You can switch the stack while debugging which should give you access to "this"

Comment: Thank you, very useful information. However, lately I have been thrown into iOS dev and on the Android side I am now using mainly Kotlin. I should probably check the state of this "issue" and maybe answer or close this questions.