# Android studio 3.3.1:Some breakpoints are shown without the tick and not being hit

Tags: android, debugging, breakpoints

I have updated my Android studio to 3.3.1. Now, some breakpoints are shown red 
(The lines that have *if*, *while* ,...) without the tick and are not being hit.

[image]

(line 67)

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: Same here with Mac version... I opened an issue, but no juice so far...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Breakpoints not working on Android Studio 3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54311642/breakpoints-not-working-on-android-studio-3-3)

Answer (score 1):

Try File>Invalidate cashes/Restart

Comment: Thanks Kourosh, I did what you said, still not working. Actually I think there is some problem with Androis Studio 3.3.1 (Windows 64bit)

Comment: I think you should open another project to see if the problem is with your project or Android Studio. try Ctrl + Shift + F8 shortcut to remove all breakpoints.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add a blank line (or two) before the IF.

Answer (score 0):

I try to adding blank line before the breakpoint but not worked.
Instead I write a dummy line code, like:
`Log.v("Breakpoints", "are dumb");`
run the code again.An now the tick is shown and breakpoint get hit.